# How to fix issue with audio.play()?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, typeerror

I am trying to use the JavaScript Audio object. I am following this guide very closely: https://medium.com/@bryanjenningz/how-to-record-and-play-audio-in-javascript-faa1b2b3e49b.

In part 6, I am supposed to call play() on an Audio object, but I am receiving an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: audio.play is not a function" and I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly. Any help?

Edit: Code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Audio extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showButton: true,
    };
  }

  recordAudio = () => {
    this.setState({ showButton: false })

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      this.setState({ mediaRecorder: new MediaRecorder(stream) })
      this.state.mediaRecorder.start();

      const audioChunks = [];

      this.state.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      });

      this.state.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        console.log(audio);
        audio.play();
      });
    });
  }

  stopRecording = () => {
    this.setState({ showButton: true })
    this.state.mediaRecorder.stop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      {/* This is a ternary operator that changes the button that is shown  */}
      {
        this.state.showButton ?
        <button type="button" onClick={this.recordAudio}> Start Recording </button> :
        <button type="button" onClick={this.stopRecording}> Stop Recording </button>
      }

      </div>

    )
  }

}

export default Audio;
```

Edit: console.log(audio) output:

```
Audio {props: undefined, context: undefined, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, recordAudio: ƒ, …}
    context:undefined
    props:undefined
    recordAudio:ƒ ()
    refs:{}
    state:{showButton: true}
    stopRecording:ƒ ()
    updater:{isMounted: ƒ, enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ, enqueueReplaceState: ƒ, enqueueSetState: ƒ}
    isMounted:(...)
    replaceState:(...)
    __proto__:ReactComponent
```

Comment: Please provide us with the code that you have written so far.

Comment: What `console.log(audio)` returns?

Comment: Thank you for updating your post. As Misha mentioned, what does `console.log(audio)` output?

Comment: I have added the console.log(audio) output. Do you have any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: In this context, `Audio` is your component's class, not the default `window.Audio` constructor. So the best would be that your rename your class to something more specific. An other **less good** solution might be to call `window.Audio`if you didn't overwrote it with your class. And an equally less good solution is to call `audio = document.createElement('audio'); audio.preload = 'auto'; audio.src = url` since it is what the default Audio does.

Answer (score 1):

Kaiido's comment solved the issue for me. Since I had named my class "Audio" and was calling the "Audio" constructor (when I thought I was calling window.Audio), it was not creating the appropriate object.

As per their solution, either rename the class, call window.Audio, or call the default window.Audio functionality as detailed in their comment.